# Why map in clojure is returning an async chan rather than a sequence of strings?

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure and currently stuck with the map function.I tried the following code:

```
(map #(str "Hello " % "!" ) ["Ford" "Arthur" "Tricia"])
```

it's returning:

```
#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x2eaf8b7c "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@2eaf8b7c"]
```

though i wanted:

```
("Hello Ford!" "Hello Arthur!" "Hello Tricia!"])
```

I was following 
[the `clojure.core/map` documentation example](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) but it isn't working as expected..

Comment: have you used `(use clojure.core.async)` or `(require [clojure.core.async :refer :all])` ? looks like the `map` from `core.async` shadows the map from clojure.core. Try to call `(meta #'map)` this would show you where the  `map` function comes from

Comment: yes i have, it's return some object not error. `:file "clojure/core/async.clj"`

Comment: the advice is just not to use/refer the whole namespace, because it leads to this class of errors. Just use `(:refer [clojure.core.async :as ca])` so you can call it's functions like `(ca/map ...)` and the core's map would function as expected. Otherwise if for some reason you can't do that, just use fully qualified name for core map: `(clojure.core/map ...)`

Comment: thanks i got it now

Comment: though i still want to know how to get the value from `#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x2eaf8b7c"clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@2eaf8b7c"]` this object.

Comment: simplest way is `(clojure.core.async/into [] %your_channel%)` , there are more in [core-async docs](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async)

Comment: @leetwinski if you post this as an answer then i'll vote for it, and it will be more useful to folks googleing for this kind of thing, which is good for all of us.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have probably replaced `clojure.core/map` with `clojure.core.async/map`. The most common way this would happen is by doing something at your repl like this (note the many warnings that tell you about this when you do so):

```
user=> (use 'clojure.core.async)
WARNING: reduce already refers to: #'clojure.core/reduce in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/reduce
WARNING: take already refers to: #'clojure.core/take in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/take
WARNING: map already refers to: #'clojure.core/map in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/map
WARNING: transduce already refers to: #'clojure.core/transduce in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/transduce
WARNING: into already refers to: #'clojure.core/into in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/into
WARNING: partition already refers to: #'clojure.core/partition in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/partition
WARNING: merge already refers to: #'clojure.core/merge in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/merge
WARNING: partition-by already refers to: #'clojure.core/partition-by in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'clojure.core.async/partition-by
```

You can always refer unambiguously to a function with it's qualified name:

```
(clojure.core/map #(str "Hello " % "!" ) ["Ford" "Arthur" "Tricia"])
```

Generally, though it's best to avoid using `use` and instead `require` the other namespace and give it an alias instead:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as async])
```

That way, your `clojure.core/map` can still be used as `map` (as all clojure.core functions are auto-referred) and the async version can be referred to as `async/map`.